# Python Pandas. Extract rows with differing number of columns and sub-strings from string columns containing a secondary separator

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tab-delimited file like this:

```
10  5040637 rs2518044;rs536681963   CG  TG  C
10  34398820    rs150406373 C   G
10  35040637    rs532547811 TCCC    T
```

Using Python pandas, I would like to:

1) Extract the first 4 columns.
2) In cases where there are strings of the kind "rs2518044;rs536681963" or "rs2518044;rs536681963;rs1111", I want to extract the part before the first ";".

I would get something like this:

```
10  5040637     rs2518044   CG
10  34398820    rs150406373 C
10  35040637    rs532547811 TCCC
```

Comment: So this is in txt file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex expression related function such as [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to capture the group before the first ';'.  This would work much better than rolling your own lambda functions, if the text match pattern is more complex than just capturing the group in front the first ';'

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   col0      col1                   col2  col3 col4  col5
0    10   5040637  rs2518044;rs536681963    CG   TG     C
1    10  34398820            rs150406373     C    G  None
2    10  35040637            rs532547811  TCCC    T  None

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
   col0      col1                   col2  col3 col4  col5
0    10   5040637  rs2518044;rs536681963    CG   TG     C
1    10  34398820            rs150406373     C    G  None
2    10  35040637            rs532547811  TCCC    T  None

In [17]: df2 = df.drop(columns=['col4', 'col5'])

In [18]: df2['col2'] = df.col2.str.extract('^([^;]+)', expand=False)

In [19]: df2
Out[19]: 
   col0      col1         col2  col3
0    10   5040637    rs2518044    CG
1    10  34398820  rs150406373     C
2    10  35040637  rs532547811  TCCC
```

Comment: Hi @CT Zhu, my I ask you how would you read the file in my example? I notice you added "None" to white spaces. Many thanks

Comment: Did do anything special, just `pd.read_clipboard(header=None)`.  If we read it from an actual file such as `pd.read_table('YOUFILE.tsv', header=None, sep='\t')` the missing data will probably show up as `nan`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a split in `;` for that column and keep the first element. For the last column you can use `drop`.

Here the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.tsv', sep='\t', names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

df.c = df.c.apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])
df.drop(labels=['e', 'f'], axis=1)
df


    a   b           c               d
0   10  5040637     rs2518044       CG
1   10  34398820    rs150406373     C
2   10  35040637    rs532547811     TCCC
```